# Extracting .jar file with command line

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to extract the files from a .jar file. How do I do that using command line?

I am running Windows 7

Answer (score 220, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html):

> To extract the files from a jar file, use `x`, as in:
>
> ```
> C:\Java> jar xf myFile.jar
> ```
>
> To extract only certain files from a jar file, supply their filenames:
>
> ```
> C:\Java> jar xf myFile.jar foo bar
> ```

The folder where `jar` is probably isn't `C:\Java` for you, on my Windows partition it's:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk[some_version_here]\bin
```

Unless the location of `jar` is in your path environment variable, you'll have to specify the full path/run the program from inside the folder.

**EDIT:** Here's another article, specifically focussed on extracting JARs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html

Comment: Ok, When I do that jar xf... command, I get the error: 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. How do I fix this?

Comment: @BobbyC: Specify the full path of `jar.exe` or run it from inside the folder.

Comment: java.io.IOException: META-INF : could not create directory
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:928)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:852)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:242)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1149) how to remove this error?

Comment: @AnilPatel I fixed this by running the command prompt as administrator (right click "run as administrator")

Comment: here's a stupid question - if I do this right (fixed the error messages I received first time), where are these files going to be extracted to?  I've checked the jdk folder and the folder of the jar file to extract but I don't see any new files

Comment: @jessieloo in my case they were in the folder from which I run the command

Answer (score 52):

Note that a jar file is a Zip file, and any Zip tool (such as 7-Zip) can look inside the jar.

Answer (score 51):

In Ubuntu:

`unzip file.jar -d dir_name_where_extracting`

Comment: Useful for systems that don't have a `jar` command! Works without any issues on CentOS 5.7

Comment: This work on Mac too. 
unzip file.jar

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following command: `jar xf rt.jar`

Where `X` stands for extraction and the `f` would be any options that indicate that the JAR file from which files are to be extracted is specified on the command line, rather than through stdin.

Answer (score 3):

Java has a class specifically for zip files and one even more specifically for Jar Files.

```
java.util.jar.JarOutputStream
java.util.jar.JarInputStream
```

using those you could, on a command from the console, using a scanner set to system.in

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = console.nextLine();
```

then get all the components and write them as a file.

```
JarEntry JE = null;
while((JE = getNextJarEntry()) != null)
{
    //do stuff with JE
}
```

You can also use java.util.zip.ZipInputStream instead, as seeing a JAR file is in the same format as a ZIP file, ZipInputStream will be able to handle the Jar file, in fact JarInputStream actually extends ZipInputStream.

an alternative is also instead of getNextJarEntry, to use getNextEntry

Answer (score 3):

`jar xf myFile.jar`

change myFile to name of your file

this will save the contents in the current folder of .jar file

that should do :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the jar command did not work. I made a copy of the jar file and changed the extension to .zip. Then right click on the .zip file and select 'Extract All'. This extracted all the files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Given a file named Me.Jar:

1. Go to cmd
2. Hit Enter
3. Use the Java `jar` command -- I am using jdk1.8.0_31 so I would type

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\jar xf me.jar

That should extract the file to the folder bin. Look for the file .class in my case my Me.jar contains a Valentine.class

Type `java Valentine` and press Enter and your message file will be opened.

Answer (score -3):

To extract the jar into specified folder use this command via command prompt

```
C:\Java> jar xf myFile.jar -C "C:\tempfolder"
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `-C` can only be used when creating jar files.

Comment: @unwichtich In that case, is there a way to specify destination folder?

Comment: On Linux systems you could use `unzip file.jar -d dir_name_where_extracting`, on Windows you have to copy/move your JAR to the destination folder and then extract it there...