# Extracting JAR file via command line error

Tags: jar, cmd

I feel really stupid asking this, however the existing string of answers to this question, while they do answer the question, do not work for me and I'm not able to comment on that exiting post to ask why (I'm new and have no reputation so I'm not allowed). For reference, this is the original Q&A string: [Extracting .jar file with command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453543/extracting-jar-file-with-command-line)

I get the same error mentioned in the string that "jar is not recognized as an internal or external command,..." and no matter what I do I cannot get it to run.  I tried changing directory to where the jar file is located, then run "jar xf", I tried going to the root and then doing a "jar xf" on the full file path, and yes I am running cmd as admin.

In the meantime, I did use the advice I saw about 7-zip, and that worked great.

Still, I am bothered that command line didn't work for me and I really want to know why and what I'm doing wrong. I know it's something simple I am missing but because I'm in a loop of frustration, I'm not able to see it.

Thanks in advance and apologies for the duplication,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Anderson Cadre\JIRA

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Anderson Cadre\JIRA>jar xp Language.jar
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Anderson Cadre\JIRA>jar xp C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Anderso
n Cadre\JIRA\Language.jar
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Anderson Cadre\JIRA>cd C:\

C:\>jar xf C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Anderson Cadre\JIRA\Language.jar
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

Tried the command from @Compo, but was told "File Not Found".  If I could attach screen prints, I would attach a screen print of the folder and the JAR file...

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Owner>DIR/B/S/A-D C:\jar.*
File Not Found

C:\Users\Owner>

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Comment: As you have linked to a previous question, and said you'd tried everything, could you please explain where **jar** is located on your system. **Type `DIR/B/S/A-D C:\jar.*`** and let us know what is returned by editing your question. Then let us know whether that location is included in 'the path'. **Type `PATH` to find out**.

Comment: @Stefan, yes I have Java installed.

Comment: @Compo, I'm not sure I understand what you need to see - is the excerpt of what I typed into my original post not giving you that info?  The file is located on C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Anderson Cadre\JIRA, the jar is named Language.jar

Comment: No, just humor me and type in the commands I asked editing your question accordingly. (see my answer).

Comment: @Compo, yes sorry I did do it, but it took a while so just now updated my original question per your request - doesn't seem like it worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have jar installed, you cannot therefore use it.

A ***.jar** file is completely different to a **jar.exe** file.

Comment: Ah.  :)  Thanks @Compo.